# Shell script to sort file list naturally (non-alphanumerically) with added difficulties

Tags: shell, sorting, awk

I have a list of files (piped from `ls`). Ideally I want it to look like this:

```
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200_1.JPG
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200_2.JPG
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200_3.JPG
[...]
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200_9.JPG
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200_9_1.JPG
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200_9_2.JPG
[...]
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200_9_10.JPG
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200_9_11.JPG
[...]
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200_9_47.JPG
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200_9_48.JPG
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200_9_49.JPG
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200Map_001.JPG
THISPARTISALWAYSTHESAME200Map_002.JPG
```

I'm piping this list into an ImageMagick `convert` function to make it into a PDF, so it would be nice to have the files in the right order, as above. However, `ls` does not sort them naturally, resulting in the 1-10-11-12-2-20 mess; `ls -v` sorts them naturally but puts the Maps at the start, and various `awk` and `sort` functions I've found cannot handle the Map bit and make an even more interesting mess.

I thought that it might not be so difficult to take the output of `ls -v` and use awk to move every line containing the string 'map' to the end, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls -v | awk '{ if($0!~/Map/) print $0; else later[NR]=$0; } END { for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) if ( i in later ) print later[i]; }'
```

Comment: Beautiful, except the Maps aren't sorted numerically. It might help that they always have 3-digit padding? (These directories are terrible, but consistent).

Comment: Thanks! That works wonderfully, now I'm going to sit down with an awk reference and try to understand _how_. :P

Comment: +1. You can make the awk script a bit shorter if you use some implicit rules, e.g.: `/Map/ { later[++j] = $0; next} 1; END { for (i=1; i<=j; i++) print later[i] }`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with two invocations of `ls` and some [glob/extended-glob patterns](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns):

```
{ ls -v !(*Map*); ls -v *Map*; } | convert ...
```